# how to 'readOnly = true' a json schema field if its value passes a certain condition?

Tags: angular, jsonschema

I have a checkbox field in my json schema that I want to disable (readOnly) if the checkbox is checked (i.e true).
I'm using the ngx schema form.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use [disabled]=true or [disabled]=false based on the value of your json schema. If the value is true, its disabled otherwise its not

Comment: and where do i put that?

Comment: inside the input tag  <input type="text" [disabled]="'true'" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Last Name">